# Multiple Broadcast Receivers for the same Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have a Bluetooth class that gets instantiated for each bluetooth connection to a device. I'm opening 2 bluetooth socket connections. Each instantiation has a broadcast receiver that receives the BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED intent when the connection has been established. The problem I'm facing is that, when the 2nd device is about to establish a connection, both broadcast receivers are notified of the BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED intent. Is there a way to notify the actual device that was connected and not both receiving a copy of the intent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with using Bluetooth, but in general when I want to target at broadcast to a specific instance I add a String extra with a unique ID. Try adding the MAC address of the device as a String extra to the intent, and checking against it in your `BroadcastReceiver` implementation.

Comment: Figured it out. The multiple intents were for the same instance.